# How to run Resque workers on different servers but polling jobs from one redis server

Tags: ruby, redis, resque

How do I run Resque workers on different servers but polling jobs from one Redis server?

As resque using redis to leep all jobs, i am looking for a way to pass parameter to worker class so a worker can connect to other redis server.

I need this because the one server do not have enough resource to run all workers.

Comment: With regards to running resque worker on different server I highy unlike there is  a way since the worker need the rails environment to backed with it along with Redis (one can move redis but what abt environment) if you can do it all will be good

Answer (score 5):

You'll just need to configure Resque to connect to a specific Redis instance. By default Resque tries to connect on localhost. Just create or modify a `config/resque.yml` as described [here](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/1-x-stable/README.markdown). It will probably need to contain something like this:

```
production: my-one-and-only-redis-instance-address.com:6379
```

You'll probably want to make sure the redis server accepts connections only from the servers you have resque workers on using IP filtering at the OS level.

Comment: Just a question how would resque worker take the rails environment into account since the OP intend to run resque worker on different server

Comment: By default resque tries to connect on localhost, so resque running on servers A and B will try to connect to redis on servers A and B respectively. But, if they are both configured to point to server C, then they will both be connecting to the same remote redis instance instead of local. This allows you to have many servers processing work from the same work queue.

Comment: Just to clarify, the entire rails app would need to be deployed to every server where you want workers running. The server containing the redis instance wouldn't necessarily need the rails app, unless you want workers running directly on it too. The best approach if you are going to have many servers running resque workers is to have the redis server they all point to run nothing but redis. Most big rails apps have multiple app servers (serving web content), multiple background worker servers, and dedicated servers for data services (redis, mysql, mongo, etc).

Comment: That the one I was asking for you cannot do that without the `rails` app in every server which is thought is `OP` did not want I believe

Comment: After reading the OP's question again it read like he is having trouble with a single server processing all the resque background jobs, so he wants to add additional background workers and have them work off the same work queue, "polling jobs from one Redis server". I don't see anything about constraints with deploying the environment to multiple servers. But, OP appears to have forgotten so we'll probably never be sure.